# How can I add appointment id/data to the link appended to the body of this appointment in Microsoft Exchange?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

Just like in the title. I would like users using Outlook to be able to click a link in the appointment which will redirect them to the site with additional data about this meeting. This link should be available in a few seconds after creating this appointment, best immidiately. The link may contain either id to this meeting in Exchange or date, time and room.

Is it possible by using transport rules? I couldn't find anything relevant.

Second way to achieve it may be a service which will scan appointments and append relevant link, but it should work every few seconds and be fully reliable.

Any other way? I can't see anything in message/appointment headers :/

I would like to support Exchange versions from 2010 up to Online.

[image: View in outlook]

Comment: You need to include in your question details of how your programatically creating the appointment and API's your using

Comment: I'm not using code and API. I'm looking for solution similar to transport rules. I can see that it may be possible with Outlook macros (oldish) or add-ons https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/index.md , but I'm still looking for but centralized solution which may be more suitable and controllable.

Comment: If you not looking to write code then Stackoverflow isn't the correct place to be asking such a question. Try https://serverfault.com

Comment: I'm not using code to create appointment, but I have nothing against using some scripts to add the link, sorry for lack of clarity. I'm not the side which creates the appointment, but one just editing it.